# ng-controller does not output correctly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I try to run the following trivial HTML:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html ng-app="tempApp">
<head>
    <script src="js_libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js_libs/angular/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="TempCtrl">
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Enter temperature :</h2><input type="number" ng-model="temp">
        <p ng-show="temp < 17">{{temp}} is too short !</p>
        <p ng-show="temp = 17">{{temp}} is OK !</p>
        <p ng-show="temp > 17">{{temp}} is too high !</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

File controller.js is:

```
  var app=angular.module("tempApp", []);

 app.controller("TempCtrl", function ($scope){
     $scope.temp = 17;
 });
```

The problems are:

1. The output shows the input box with 17 default and the message  *17 is ok*. I can not change the value in the input box, neither by clicking on the arrows nor by entering direct data.
2. At the same time, trying to apply tags such as < h1 > to < p > has no effect. I tried for example:

   ```
        <p ng-show="temp < 17"><h1>{{temp}} is too short !</h1></p>
   ```

What is the solution for these problems ? Thanx.

Comment: you are setting temp = 17 instead of checking temp == or === 17 in the second case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding the first problem:

use `temp == 17` or `temp === 17` for comparison, instead of `temp = 17`, which assigns 17 to temp and hence you cannot change the value anymore.

regarding `h1` inside `p`:

It is invalid HTML, and so when the browser encounters `h1` inside `p`, it closes the `p` tag, then starts a new `h1` tag, so in your case, if you write

```
<p ng-show="temp < 17">
    <h1> too short </h1>
</p>
```

then the browser would render it as

```
<p ng-show="temp < 17"></p>
<h1> too short </h1>
<p></p>
```

P.S: can't say about all browsers, but chrome and probably firefox have this behavior.

Comment: To all: about "==" or "===" your right.I make the modification. about <p>: I made the following modifiction: <h2><p ng-show="temp < 17">{{temp}} is too short !</p></h2>  (for all the <p> lines). And is OK. Thanx.

Answer (score 4):

You have the value 17 assigned in your ng-show. Comparing the value should be via == or ===. That should solve majority of your problem.

```
<p ng-show="temp === 17">{{temp}} is OK !</p>
```

Comment: Better to use === instead of ==

Answer (score 0):

You're using assigning operator instead of comparing operator

Solution :

```
<p ng-show="temp = 17">{{temp}} is OK !</p>
```

change to =>

```
<p ng-show="temp === 17">{{temp}} is OK !</p>
```